# How can I iterate my code a 1000 times?

Tags: functions, functional-style

this is my solution to Exercise 5 of http://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw2.pdf
Please help me make this more elegant.

The exercise is about classifying random Points by a (randomly generated) target function to 2 classes (-1 and +1), build a new target function by linear Regression and compare where they don't classify to the same value.

first I generate two Random Points to build the target function

```
funktionsPunkte = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}]
```

then generate the target function from it (to classify the data points)

```
targetFct[{x1_, x2_}] := 
With[{targetFunction = LinearModelFit[funktionsPunkte, {1, t}, t]}, 
x2 - targetFunction[x1]];
```

then I generate 100 data Points and classify them to either +1 or -1 ,depending if they are above or below the target function

```
data = With[{points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}]}, 
Map[{Prepend[#, 1], If[targetFct[#] < 0, -1, 1]} &, points]];
```

one data Point is of the form {{1,x1,x2},y} where y is either +1 or -1.

now Comes the ugly part. I Need the weight vector w = PseudoInverse[{1,x1,x2}].y

```
w = (PseudoInverse[#[[1]] & /@ data]).(#[[2]] & /@ data)
```

only {1,x1,x2} :

```
xlist = (#[[1]] &) /@ data;
```

the sign of each element w.x (-1 or 1 depending on which class we classify it)

```
 sig = Sign /@ (w.# &) /@ xlist ;
```

only the y of our data Points

```
datasig = #[[2]] & /@ data;
```

now we Count the "misclassified" elements

```
Length[Select[
 Table[sig[[i]] != datasig[[i]], {i, 100}], # == True &]]
```

now I Need to repeat this Experiment a 1000 times and take the mean. But how do I do that.
I'm coming from an imperative Point of view and this would be trivial there.

I'm also welcoming more elegant Solutions that more use functional and mathematica specific elements.

edit:

thanks to the comments, I made this

```
f := Module[{}, funktionsPunkte = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
 targetFct[{x1_, x2_}] := 
 With[{targetFunction = LinearModelFit[funktionsPunkte, {1, t}, t]},
 x2 - targetFunction[x1]];
 data = With[{points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}]}, 
 Map[{Prepend[#, 1], If[targetFct[#] < 0, -1, 1]} &, points]];
 w = (PseudoInverse[#[[1]] & /@ data]).(#[[2]] & /@ data);
 xlist = (#[[1]] &) /@ data;
 sig = Sign /@ (w.# &) /@ xlist;
 datasig = #[[2]] & /@ data;
 Length[Select[
 Table[sig[[i]] != datasig[[i]], {i, 100}], # == True &]]]
```

and then

```
f & /@ Range[1000]
```

it's awfully slow but it works (have not implemented the other suggestions yet)

Comment: Pack your steps into one function and repeat $n$ times. `Module` or similar are useful for that. You can merge separate cells, but make sure you use the right amount of `;`.

Comment: I should mention that this is an ungraded homework from a mooc course of caltech

Comment: `funktionsPunkte`, some Denglish there :D

Comment: Why don't you wait after it is graded?

Comment: @RolfMertig he said ungraded, right? Also from the homework: "You are also encouraged to take part in the forum [other forum] where there are lots of threads about each homework"

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom true, but my question is more mathematica oriented so I thought I'm better off here. As far as I've read the Forum, most People use octave/matlab, python or even Java to solve the Problems.

Comment: Note that you are recalculating a new linear model in each call to `targetFct`. `With[{a = slow[] }, f[x_] := a[x] ]` calculates it only once

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One part of your question is about iteration. Building on Yves comment, one good way is to pack everything inside a function. To simplify your problem, say the function is:

```
f := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
```

Each time `f` is called, you get a new random number. (This greatly simplifies your problem, but the same idea holds.) Now to iterate 1000 times, you can use `Map`

```
f & /@ Range[1000]
```

and you get a list of the function, evaluated 1000 times.

In your case, you have a more complex function... `Module` will let you nicely place lots of commands together:

```
f := Module[{}, statement1; statement2; Sign[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]]]
```

Again, `f & /@ Range[1000]` will iterate this 1000 times.

Answer (score 3):

You use  `#[[i]]&/@somelist` a lot when instead you can use a part specification like: `somelist[[All, i]]` to get the i-th column.

To count miss-classified you can look at the difference of the lists and count all non-zero elements like:

```
Length[Select[Table[sig[[i]] != datasig[[i]], {i, 100}], # == True &]]

(* Same as: *)
Total@Unitize[sig - datasig]
```

The function `Sign` is `Listable` which means you don't have to use `Map`:

```
Sign[{-1, 2, 1}]
(* {-1, 1, 1} *)
```